# Play sound on hover in Adobe AIR HTML app

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm making a HTML-based Adobe AIR application where I want to play a beep sound when a user hovers over a link. The mouseenter event is handled by jQuery and then calls a function. For the Web it uses the Web Audio API (powered by Howl.js) but because AIR does not support the API I fallback to use the Flash API.

What I have so far is:

```
// if Adobe AIR
if (window.runtime){
            var myChannel = new window.runtime.flash.media.SoundChannel();
            var beep;
            $('ul.menu a').on('mouseenter', function(){
                // stop all sounds... (should I be stopping all sounds though?)
                window.runtime.flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
                // set beep as a new sound
                beep = new window.runtime.flash.media.Sound();
                // load mp3
                beep.load(new URLRequest('./assets/beep.mp3'));
                // once file has loaded
                beep.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, function(){
                    myChannel = beep.play();
                });
            });

// we're running in the browser
} else {

    var sound = new Howl({
      urls: ['./assets/beep.mp3', './assets/beep.ogg']
    });

    $('ul.menu a').on('mouseenter', function(){                 
        sound.play();
    });

}
```

But it doesn't work... What have I done wrong?

Comment: is this code js or as3? it looks like you're trying to directly run as3 code in the browser

Comment: No the ActionScript part doesn't run in the browser! It's run inside Adobe AIR. And you can use ActionScript and JavaScript mixed together in AIR HTML apps... but I think I need to prefix them with `window.runtime.flash`... but not sure about the events.

Comment: Don't you need to call constructor with () ?
Like:
 `var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
var myChannel = new window.runtime.flash.media.SoundChannel();
var beep;
$('a').on('mouseenter', function(){

    // stop all sounds... (should I be stopping all sounds though?)
    window.runtime.flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
    // set beep as a new sound
    beep = new window.runtime.flash.media.Sound();
    // load mp3
    beep.load(new air.URLRequest('./assets/beep.mp3'));

    // once file has loaded
    beep.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, function(){
        myChannel = beep.play();
    });
});
```

However you don't need `myChannel` and could just call `beep.play();`

In fact you can do it with three lines:

```
var beep = new air.Sound();
beep.load(new air.URLRequest('./assets/beep.mp3'));
beep.play();
```